# Creating breed tags

Tags: discussion, tags, editing, retagging

The consensus from this post [Should we have tags for breeds?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/should-we-have-tags-for-breeds) is that when there's 3-4 posts on a breed that it would be appropriate to create a breed tag.

I created a [german-shepherd](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-shepherd) and retagged the relevant posts with the breed. The breed tag should only be used if the breed is relevant to the post. For some questions the breed is incidental to the actual problem. I also created a [pug](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pug) as I'm aware there's pug questions, but only retagged the one when I added the [german-shepherd](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-shepherd) tag. I didn't continue searching for pug questions or other breeds, as I don't want to flood the active questions with posts that have been edited by me.

I'm thinking three things:

**1. Is it time for the community to look at adding breed tags?**

While the question pool is still relatively small, [it's easier to search on breed names in questions](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=pug%20is%3Aquestion) and retag them.

**2. Should this be a community effort?**

Do we want more than one person to be doing the retagging?

**3.  Do we create breed tags on new questions asked that are breed specific?**

To save retrospectively adding the tag to questions as the site build?

Comment: As a mod, can't you do tag edits without bumping?

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver that's a good question, I am not sure. I will need to check this

Answer (score 3):

My general inclination is that adding breed tags is not useful information.

I tend to rescue Siamese cats (mostly mixes), which have a very particular constellation of traits.

- very social with people
- very loud and frequent vocalizations
- bad teeth/mouth structures
- neurological eye problems
- blue eyes
- colorpoint coat pattern

Yet, cats who are not Siamese can also exhibit all of these traits. In fact, of the 8 cats I've had in the last 12 years, the one who had the worst dental problems was a DSH.

Even the most Siamese cat particular question I've asked applies to other cat breeds/types: [What's the difference between chocolate and seal colorpoints (Siamese)?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9675/whats-the-difference-between-chocolate-and-seal-colorpoints-siamese) Some cats have the Siamese color, but none of the other traits. Some cats have all of the other traits, but not the color.

None of the [german-shepherd](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german-shepherd) questions have questions that are EXCLUSIVE to a German Shepherd. They are just general dog questions and should be tagged [dogs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs) and the nature of the problem.

Comment: hm, I think you make a good point about cat breeds and differentiation and I'm thinking it might be a good issue generally. Maybe with dogs we could have small, medium, large?

Comment: @YvetteColomb will have to think about size tags some more. I'm having trouble seeing where the size really affects the question, but I'm not super familiar with dogs and will probably dive through the questions to find examples/counter examples.

Answer (score 3):

My concern is that it becomes a [Meta-Tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) if the question doesn't specifically relate to that breed.

For example, if you tag a question as 'King Charles Spaniel' and you're just asking about 'how to make it sit' then the breed is pretty much irrelevant (just as Zaralynda points out with cats).

In some situation there might be instances where breed *is* relevant (such as 'The correct environment to breed Discus' where there are special requirements) but a good answer should provide the context requirements of the breed without the OP having to specify it within the questions tags.

It sounds to me like it will become extremely noisy, extremely quickly if we start having breed tags (not least because of the sheer number of breeds of *all* types of pet).

Hopefully the question would receive the answers that it needs just being tagged as [fish](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish) and [breeding](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breeding).